# How i can get Rod sizes in Rod Cut using Recrsivly?

Tags: c++

I want to get rod size of maximum revenue in rod ct problem.
suppose there is 4 length of rod.

```
1 = 5
2 = 4
3 = 3
4 = 10
```

in this situation, maximum revenue will generate by 1,1,1,1 which is 20.
i got maximum revenue but how i can get rod size 
here is the code.

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int Rod_Cut(int *,int);
int main()
{
    const int n=5;
    int arr[n]={0,5,4,3,10};
    int size[n]={0};


    cout<<Rod_Cut(arr,n)<<endl;


}

int Rod_Cut(int *arr, int n)
{
    if(n==0)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    int q=0;

    for(int i=1;i<n;i++)
    {

        q=max(q,arr[i]+Rod_Cut(arr,n-i));


    }

    return q;
}
```

Comment: have you tried anything to find its size?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and reformulate your question.

Comment: Am I correct that this is a homework problem? May I suggest that you try to understand and solve it on your own? There is probably lots of information online as well, e.g. http://www.radford.edu/~nokie/classes/360/dp-rod-cutting.html.

Comment: If you are seeking help on StackOverflow it usually pays of to be as specific as possible. Did you read the two links?

Comment: I don't know what this means. I think it's like Blackjack but you are not supposed to go over 20. You need recursive functions to make permutations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one approach:

You need to return the sequence used in each calculation. If the new value is better than what you have so far, you must save the new "best" sequence. In the end you return the best sequence found.

The proposal is not optimal (e.g. performance) but maybe it will give you some ideas. Then you can optimize the code to perform better.

Good luck.

```
int Rod_Cut(int *,int, vector<int>&);
int main()
{
    const int n=5;
    int arr[n]={0,5,8,3,10};
    int size[n]={0};

    vector<int> v;  // Create vector for the best sequence
    cout<<Rod_Cut(arr,n,v)<<endl;

    // Print the best sequence
    for(auto e : v)
    {
        cout << e << " ";
    }


}

int Rod_Cut(int *arr, int n, vector<int>& v)
{
    if(n==0)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    int q=0;

    vector<int> t;        // Temp vector for next call
    vector<int> st;       // The best sequence found at this level
    for(int i=1;i<n;i++)
    {
        int temp = arr[i]+Rod_Cut(arr,n-i,t);
        if (temp > q)
        {
            // A new better sequence has been found

            st.clear();        // clear the former best sequence
            for(auto e : t)    // add the new best sequence
            {
                st.push_back(e);
            }
            st.push_back(i);   // add i used at this level
            q = temp;
        }

        t.clear();   // Prepare for next call
    }

    // Copy the best sequence to the returned vector
    for (auto e : st)
    {
        v.push_back(e);
    }

    return q;
}
```